# Annoying problem w/ xrdp

Tags: xrdp

i had to install an linux based server, so after facing many problems over and over again, i finally managed to overcome all of them

so now i was configuring the xrdp and at the first look, everything worked fine, but then came the problem i cant find a way to fix it at all

here at my work we have lots of computers, and only 2 of them run linux, the rest is all windows, and them problem is at UI remote conection between windows/linux

when some1 use windows native remote app, that person can connect without problems, you can even share files with the remote computer (the server one) by the thinclient thing, but just at the very first time..

when a user ends his session, later, after coming back and starting a new session, at trying to open the thinclient_drives again, its doesnt work

the user receive the following error:
error message without handling: error getting information for the file. Endpoint transport is not connected.

i didnt get it at all, because the first time some1 logs in, it works perfectly, you can even quit the remote conection without ending your session and coming back later, and everything will still working

however, if you do finish your session and log back again later, it doesnt work anymore until server reboot

i tried lots of stuff, i first tought it was some hidden session left behind, i even tried rebooting the xrdp, but the problem didnt got fixed at all

i also tried umounting, but it doesnt let me umount the thinclient

i tried the command "ps aux" to see all process runing, and killed a lot of 
them, trying to fix without reboot, but no success

no matter how hard i try, i cant find whats is going on, i know it might be some hidden process left i cant see or something else, but i dont know how to find it if it is something like that

the only solution for now is not fishing a session while leaving the remote connection, otherwhise the server has to be rebooted

at reboot, thinclient works fine again, but just once, then the same thing happens all over again

any tips on what's causing all of that or how to fix it?

Comment: Hello, lets get some information that may help in finding a solution to your problem. What distro / version of linux are you running? What version of xrdp and how did you install it?

Comment: "however, if you do finish your session and log back again later, it doesnt work anymore until server reboot" Does that mean a user logs out of their RDP session verses closing the RDP window?

Comment: im using ubuntu 18.04,
after doing some research i figured out it would not matter installing the server version or the standart version, because i could just install samba to share files and xrdp to allow remote conection.

About the xrdp, i instaled it by terminal using apt-get install xrdp if i remember correctly

Comment: "Does that mean a user logs out of their RDP session verses closing the RDP window?" ------ What happens in fact, is that the user goes into the top-right corner of the screen and select end session, this automatically disconect him from the server, if doing this, after loging back later, the files sharing doesnt work anymore as if his session were left running with the thinclient thing mounted

Comment: about the xrdp version, how do i check the version? even thou im using ubuntu for quite some time, im still a newbie and i cant figure out the command to check this info... all i know is that i installed xrdp about 1 mounth ago by terminal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

after looking around at the internet for a way to fix that, i found a temporary solution

looks like the cause is a problem with the 18.04 version of ubuntu itself

the way to fix it is quite simple, after logging in, the first thing you should do is umounting the thinclient thing, i did that by terminal using

```
sudo umount -f thinclient_drives
```

after that, you must rename the `thinclient_drives` to `.thinclient_drives`

just add a dot before and it will fix everything, however, looks like ubuntu isnt umounting correctly when finishing the session, so, you gotta umount manualy every time, that way, it will work and mount correctly the next time you log in

im gonna try to see now if its possible to run some kind of command before logging off, if it is, then ill fix it by setting a command to umount everytime b4 login out

Comment: +1 - this worked.  The thinclient_drives folder is located in the Home/ directory.  Thank you so much for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

vi(m) the `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` file.

Under [Chansrv] add:
`FuseMountName=/tmp/%u/thinclient_drives`

Log out and log back in. The thinclient_drives will now be mounted in `/tmp/{uid}/thinclient_drives`.

You can `rmdir thinclient_drives` in your homedir.

Answer (score 1):

I like all the answers here and for me, the most efficient way to solve this problem is to combine both methods by using sed to to look in `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` and change `FuseMountName=thinclient_drives` to `FuseMountName=.thinclient_drives` .

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set -o errexit
set -o nounset
#set -eu -o pipefail
#set -x
#trap read debug

thinclient=$(sudo cat /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini | grep FuseMountName)

if [ -z "$thinclient" ]; then
  echo 'Entry doesn'\'''t exist, adding...''
  sudo sed -i '/Chansrv/a FuseMountName=.thinclient_drives' /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini
else
  echo 'Entry exists, modifying...'
  sudo sed -i s/"$thinclient"/FuseMountName=.thinclient_drives/g /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini
fi
```

The problem should resolve itself after logging out and then back in.

Comment: Your use of quotes (``'`` and ``"``) is non-standard. You might want to research that and then [edit] your answer.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand?  Is this reference wrong? --> https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html